# Can't access my jinja2 filters

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

I have looked through the docs but can't find an answer. It's probably something stupid basic I'm missing. I have jinja2 setup w/ pyramid and am using pyramid_jinja2 and have setup my filters in my .ini file:

```
jinja2.filters =
    model_url = pyramid_jinja2.filters:model_url_filter
    route_url = pyramid_jinja2.filters:route_url_filter
    static_url = pyramid_jinja2.filters:static_url_filter
    my_filter = myapp.view.my_filter
```

(my_filter simply multiplies each value by 100)
This works fine:

```
@view_config(renderer="json",route_name="tester")
def tester(request):
    myList = [1,2,3,4]
    return render_to_response("templates/test.jinja2",{'myList':myList},request=request)
```

test.jinja2:

```
{% for l in myList %}
   {{ l | my_filter }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, this does not:

```
@view_config(renderer="json",route_name="tester")
def tester(request):
    myList = [1,2,3,4]
    tmplate = Template(u'''\
        {% for l in myList %}
           {{ l | my_filter  }}
        {% endfor %}
        ''')
    html = tmplate.render(myList = myList)
    return render_to_response("templates/test.jinja2",{'html':html},request=request)
```

test.jinja2:

```
{{ html | safe }}
```

My error message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'my_filter'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, your template is not linked with environment, where do you normally defined your filters. Template Class initialization create self-environment, with no relations with your main environment.

If you want create template dynamically from string, and keep your filters, need something like that:

```
from jinja2 import Environment

env = Environment() # main environment, basically one per program.
env.filters['my_filter'] = lambda i: i * 100
template = env.from_string('{% for i in myList %}{{ i|my_filter }}_{% endfor %}')
print(template.render(myList=range(10)))
# 0_100_200_300_400_500_600_700_800_900_
```